# Select query for selecting columns from those records from the inner query . where inner query and outer query have different columns

Tags: postgresql, select, amazon-redshift

I have a group by query which fetches me some records. What if I wish to find other column details representing those records.

Suppose I have a query as follows .`Select id,max(date) from records group by id;` 
to fetch the most recent entry in the table. 
I wish to fetch another column representing those records .

I want to do something like this (This incorrect query is just for example) :
`Select type from (Select id,max(date) from records group by id)` but here type doesnt exist in the inner query.

I am not able to define the question in a simpler manner.I Apologise for that.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT :**

```
Column |         Type          | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 id     | integer               | 
 rdate  | date                  | 
 type   | character varying(20) |
```

Sample Data :

```
 id |   rdate    | type 
----+------------+------
  1 | 2013-11-03 | E1
  1 | 2013-12-12 | E1
  2 | 2013-12-12 | A3
  3 | 2014-01-11 | B2
  1 | 2014-01-15 | A1
  4 | 2013-12-23 | C1
  5 | 2014-01-05 | C
  7 | 2013-12-20 | D
  8 | 2013-12-20 | D
  9 | 2013-12-23 | A1
```

While I was trying something like this (I'm no good at sql) : `select type from records as r1 inner join (Select id,max(rdate) from records group by id) r2 on r1.rdate = r2.rdate ;`
or

```
select type from records as r1 ,(Select id,max(rdate) from records group by id) r2 inner join r1 on r1.rdate = r2.rdate ;
```

Comment: Can you post your table definitions and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question right, then this should work (or at least get you something you can work with):

```
SELECT
    b.id, b.maxdate, a.type
FROM
    records a -- this is the records table, where you'll get the type
INNER JOIN -- now join it to the group by query
    (select id, max(rdate) as maxdate FROM records GROUP BY id) b
ON -- join on both rdate and id, otherwise you'll get lots of duplicates
    b.id = a.id
AND b.maxdate = a.rdate
```

Note that if you have records with different types for the same id and rdate combination you'll get duplicates.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying instead of a and b, I have r1 an r2 but in the join it says  column r2.rdate doesn't exist .  select type from records r1 inner join (Select id,max(rdate) from records group by id) r2 on r1.id = r2.id and r1.rdate=r2.rdate ;

Comment: You need to use an alias in your group by query. That's what the "as maxdate" does in my query. e.g.  select type from records r1 inner join (Select id,max(rdate) as max_rdate from records group by id) r2 on r1.id = r2.id and r1.rdate=r2.max_rdate

Comment: Is there a typo with i.maxdate

Comment: Now it Works . I'll check if its right .select type from records r1 inner join (Select id,max(rdate) as maxdate from records group by id) r2 on r1.id = r2.id and r1.rdate=r2.maxdate ;

Comment: Yes, there was. Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Gaah! Now fixed. Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT id, rdate, type
FROM (
  SELECT id, rdate, type, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rdate DESC) rnk
  FROM records
  WHERE rnk = 1
) foo
ORDER BY id;
```

The window definition `OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rdate DESC)` takes all records with the same `id` value, then sorts then from most recent to least recent `rdate` and assigns a rank to each row. The rank of 1 is the most recent, so equivalent to `max(rdate)`.

Comment: I will have to work on postgresql more . I will look it up.